# Retirement visa for Japan

Tags: japan, us-citizens, long-stay-visas

I retired a few yrs ago and wanted to travel to Japan for long periods of 90 days + 90 days. I lived in Tokyo for 10 yrs after college and speak the language so no problems. I'm a US citizen and wanting to visit friends throughout Japan and enjoy my retirement. What would be the best way to plan for this type of duration in Japan, after Covid19 vaccine?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What exactly do you mean by ‘best way’? As it stands, your question is likely to get close votes because what you need help with is unclear.

Comment: I think this question belongs on Expatriates.

Comment: I didn't get "trying to move there permanently" @David.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica No, not permanently. But the OP said "long periods of 90 + 90 days." The OP said he wanted to "enjoy his retirement," which suggests also to me that he's not constrained to shorter-term travel, All in all, I took the question to mean "long term."

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica The posted answer indicates that Japan sees this sort of long(ish)-term visit as "sightseeing and recreation."  I will withdraw my vote to close here.

Comment: @DavidsupportsMonica Expatriates would be correct if the goal was to take up residence in the country. That was not my impression of what was being asked.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Defining "expatriates" as those who take up "residence" doesn't help, IMO. Words mean different things at different times and different contexts. Even a traveler, who's in a foreign country for a short time, resides there during their trip. We here use the word "expatriate" to indicate a longer time, rather than a shorter one. OTOH, the Japanese immigration authorities don't do that, they take even a longer time (up to a year, as I see it) as touristic. Context is often (but perhaps not always) determinative.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica A **visitor** does not live in the country they visit:  [EXPATRIATE | meaning in the Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/expatriate) : **someone who does not live in their own country**

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica The primary usage of  National D-Visa in the Schengen Area is for a long visit up to 1 year. It is also used to start a residence and is converted to a residence permit after arrival. The possible problems for a visitor (short or long) are different than that of a resident. That is why I think that they should remain separated.

Comment: @Mark Johnson  We can differ here. Expatriates.SE has in the past addressed those who relocate for only an academic term, so I think Travel.SE can likewise address those who'd move for a longer period, but not permanently. The category boundaries  here are not rigid.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica I am comfortable with that. For an academic term you are taking up a residence for a short time. Whereas a long term visitor is generally moving around.

Answer (score 18):

The best thing to do is contact the Japanese consulate and ask if you fullfill the conditions of any long term visa.

A quick search, however, reveals one that may suit your purpose:

- [Designated activities (Long Stay for sightseeing and recreation)](https://www.mofa.go.jp/ca/fna/page22e_000738.html)

  - 6 months, renewable up to 12 months

The linked page describes the further financial and health insurance requirements.

When it becomes clear when you want to go, you will probably have to submit the application in person at the responsible consulate.

---

**Sources**:

- [Specified visa: Designated activities (Long Stay for sightseeing and recreation) | Ministry of Foreign Affairs of Japan](https://www.mofa.go.jp/ca/fna/page22e_000738.html)
- [VISA INFORMATION | Consulate-General of Japan in San Francisco](https://www.sf.us.emb-japan.go.jp/itpr_en/visa_travel.html)

Comment: The link requests for a savings of 30 million ¥ (~250k € / 270k $) per person. That seems to be a ridiculously high amount to show in cash savings for a six month visa, even for an upper middle class

Comment: @Max that's a little over 6x what I get paid in a year and I live in Japan. 